# Combine external XML files into one and orderby

Tags: php, xml, output

I have the following PHP function to combine multiple external XML files into one file:

```
<?php
    function combineXML($file) 
    { 
        global $xmlstr; 

        $xml = simplexml_load_file($file); 

        foreach($xml as $element) 
            $xmlstr .= $element->asXML(); 
    } 

    $files[] = "file1.xml"; 
    $files[] = "file2.xml"; 

    $xmlstr = '<productItems>';

    foreach ($files as $file) 
        combineXML($file); 

    $xmlstr .= '</productItems>'; 

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr); 
    $bytes = file_put_contents("output.xml", $xml->asXML());    
?>
```

Is it possible to also re-order the feed? Like having the last modified on top? So order by *lastmodified* file system date.

Comment: 1. Please make an example like a little input file and the current + expected output 2. *last modified items* <- You mean the last modified files ?

Comment: yes, you can order it, but you should do that while reading the files. e.g. get the files' timestamps, order by those timestamps, then do your building based on that ordered timestamp.

Comment: the files already have a <lastmodified> field in the feed. So there is no possibility to re order in the php file already?

Answer (score 3):

You did not provide XML examples so let's assume some simple structures:

```
$xmls = [ 
'<productItems>
  <item>
    <title>Item 1</title>
    <lastmodified>1</lastmodified>
  </item>
</productItems>',
'<productItems>
  <item>
    <title>Item 2</title>
    <lastmodified>2</lastmodified>
  </item>
</productItems>'
];
```

## Merging XMLs

I prefer using DOM. (It's easier, because here is no automagic mapping).

First create a target document and add the document element node:

```
$merged = new DOMDocument();
$merged->appendChild($merged->createElement('productItems'));
```

Next iterate the XMLs, load them into DOMs and copy all the child nodes of the document element to the target document.

```
foreach ($xmls as $xml) {
  $source = new DOMDocument();
  $source->loadXml($xml);
  foreach ($source->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
    $merged->documentElement->appendChild(
      $merged->importNode($node, TRUE)
    );
  }
}
```

Allow formatting and save the merged XML:

```
$merged->formatOutput = true;
echo $merged->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<productItems>
  <item>
    <title>Item 1</title>
    <modified>1</modified>
  </item>    
  <item>
    <title>Item 2</title>
    <modified>2</modified>
  </item>
</productItems>
```

### Working With Files

If you're working with files you have to use `DOMDocument::load()` and `DOMDocument::save()`. `DOMDocument::loadXml()/saveXml()` are for XML strings.

## Sorting Nodes

Fetch the `item` nodes from the source document using XPath and convert the node list into an array:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($merged);
$products = iterator_to_array($xpath->evaluate('//item'));
```

Sort the array using `usort`. Using XPath, you can fetch any data in the context of the node:

```
usort(
  $products,
  function($nodeOne, $nodeTwo) use ($xpath) {
    return strnatcmp(
      $xpath->evaluate('string(modified)', $nodeTwo),
      $xpath->evaluate('string(modified)', $nodeOne)
    );    
  }
);
```

Create the target document and copy the nodes into it:

```
$sorted= new DOMDocument();
$sorted->appendChild($sorted->createElement('productItems'));
foreach ($products as $node) {
  $sorted->documentElement->appendChild(
    $sorted->importNode($node, TRUE)
  );
}

$sorted->formatOutput = true;
echo $sorted->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<productItems>
  <item>
    <title>Item 2</title>
    <modified>2</modified>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Item 1</title>
    <modified>1</modified>
  </item>
</productItems>
```

Comment: Thank you for your well documented comment. Where can I add the external feeds into this code?

Comment: You just have to use `DOMDocument::load($xmlFile)` not `DOMDocument::loadXml($xmlString)`. Ditto for saving the document.